# Connect 4 AI Java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to design an AI for my connect 4 java program, there needs to be different levels of difficulties, I have created an algorithm for the easy level, but now I need another algorithm for the hard level.

Could someone recommend or give me some pseudocode for a good algorithm for the AI. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.pomakis.com/c4/connect_generic/c4.txt seems to describe the implementation of a good old pruned tree search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Connect 4 AI about 6 months ago for an AI class I was taking.

We used the Minimax algorithm with Alpha-Beta pruning.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning

(it should work fine without the Alpha-Beta pruning, but it wouldn't search as far).

Answer (score 0):

On an easy level you can create simple pattern-matching neural network. 2-level perceptron with some linear function + learing with teacher.

There is also much to do with genetic algorithms. I remember creating the island model genetic algorithm for my AI class - it was quite easy but looked like a complex system.

If you need something for hard level look at messy generic algorithm.